# Create React app with React-Snapshot Pre-Rendering static files

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, prerender

I'm using create react app with [react-snapshot](https://github.com/geelen/react-snapshot)  to pre-render static markup for my routes. i.e `"/", "/signIn", "/signUp"` generates `index.html, signIn.html, signUp.html`respectively.

Issue I'm facing is that no matter what route I go to, initially the static  `index.html` generated from  react-snapshot for the root route `"/"` is served and then the correct static route file and then the `main.js` bundle is served(see gif). This would be fine if I was just serving my app from a bundled `main.js` alone. but since I want to use the static pre-generated html files, how do I disable the the service worker from serving index.html on certain routes for which I have static html file already.

**Update:** If I remove service worker from the create react app, the app loads static file for the path fine. However, I want to keep the functionality of service worker for PWA features.

**Update 2:**  On `chrome browser` the quick flicker of root route static markup happens only once for each route. After the 1st flicker it seems the chrome browser cache fixes it, additionally if I disable cache from chrome dev tools and try to go to new route the flicker of root route returns. 
On `Firefox browser` the problem exists no matter what, on every route change or refresh the momentary flick of root route static markup occurs.

How can I avoid the index.html to be rendered initially on all routes from the service worker without removing the service worker.

**In more detail:**

With the Service Worker active the following code renders in the body of page source of all routes:

```
 <body>
 <script>window.react_snapshot_state = {};</script>
 <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
 <div id="root" data-react-checksum="-928641672"><div data-reactroot="" class="sc-cSHVUG hyLStb"><div class="sc-fjdhpX dIRAsX"><ul class="sc-gqjmRU koKaUp"><li><a class="navItemActive sc-VigVT cZrGwO" href="/"><!-- react-text: 6 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 7 -->Home<!-- /react-text --></a></li><li><a class="sc-VigVT cZrGwO" href="/aboutUs/"> About US</a></li><li><a class="sc-VigVT cZrGwO" href="/faq/"> FAQ</a></li></ul><div class="sc-jzJRlG cLytIk"><button class="ui basic circular compact icon button sc-jTzLTM jfwzMH"><i aria-hidden="true" class="user circle icon"></i></button><button class="ui basic circular compact icon button sc-jTzLTM jfwzMH"><i aria-hidden="true" class="add user icon"></i></button></div></div><!-- react-empty: 17 --><div><div style="opacity: 1;"><div class="sc-bdVaJa eRTdVS">Home</div></div></div></div></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.04df5475.js"></script></body>
```

IF I remove the Service worker the `"/signIn"` route renders the following in the body of page source:

```
<body>
 <script>window.react_snapshot_state = {};</script>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root" data-react-checksum="143569200"><div data-reactroot="" class="sc-cSHVUG hyLStb"><div class="sc-fjdhpX dIRAsX"><ul class="sc-gqjmRU koKaUp"><li><a class="sc-VigVT cZrGwO" href="/"><!-- react-text: 6 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 7 -->Home<!-- /react-text --></a></li><li><a class="sc-VigVT cZrGwO" href="/aboutUs/"> About US</a></li><li><a class="sc-VigVT cZrGwO" href="/faq/"> FAQ</a></li></ul><div class="sc-jzJRlG cLytIk"><button class="ui basic circular compact icon button sc-jTzLTM jfwzMH"><i aria-hidden="true" class="user circle icon"></i></button><button class="ui basic circular compact icon button sc-jTzLTM jfwzMH"><i aria-hidden="true" class="add user icon"></i></button></div></div><!-- react-empty: 17 --><div><div style="opacity: 1;"><div><div class="sc-EHOje bssfxk"><div class="sc-EHOje bssfxk"><form class="ui large warning form sc-ifAKCX ljuaXJ"><div class="field"><label></label><input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" value=""></div><p class="sc-bxivhb dXOlfT">error</p></form><form class="ui large warning form sc-ifAKCX ljuaXJ"><div class="field"><label></label><input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" value=""></div><p class="sc-bxivhb dXOlfT">error</p></form></div><p class="sc-dnqmqq ccTWaR"></p><div><div class="sc-gzVnrw cCgvhR"><button class="ui basic button sc-iwsKbI Vfjvd"><!-- react-text: 37 -->Login<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 38 --> <!-- /react-text --></button><div class="sc-gzVnrw cCgvhR"><!-- react-empty: 40 --><div class="ui horizontal divider" style="width: 220px;">Or</div><div class="sc-bZQynM kECAnI"><button class="ui google plus button" style="text-transform: capitalize;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="google icon"></i><!-- react-text: 45 --> Google<!-- /react-text --></button><button class="ui facebook button" style="text-transform: capitalize;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="facebook icon"></i><!-- react-text: 48 --> Facebook<!-- /react-text --></button></div></div></div><div><p class="sc-htoDjs dErAlA">forgot your password ?</p></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.04df5475.js"></script><iframe style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

**GiF shows me trying to access `"/signIn"` Route, and notice the word `home` (static markup for `"/"` route) come up for a moment before the actual form for `"/signIn"` route renders.**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that `Service Worker(SW)` by default in `Create React App` only caches contents of `static folder` and the `index.html`. My pre-rendered `.html` files from react-snapshot were never cached by the `SW`. the `SW` in `create react app` also is set to serve `index.html` for all unknown urls, thus it was serving the root path `"/"` static file `index.html.` I solved this by overwriting the `service-worker.js` file by changing the build command in `package.json` like so:

`"build": "react-scripts build && react-snapshot && sw-precache --config=sw-precache-config.js"`

where my `sw-precache-config.js` looked like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  staticFileGlobs: [
    './build/**/**.html',
    './build/images/**.*',
    './build/static/**',
  ],
  dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /\.\w{8}\./,
  swFilePath: './build/service-worker.js',
      // For unknown URLs, fallback to the index page
  navigateFallback: './200.html',
      // Ignores URLs starting from /__ (useful for Firebase):
      // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2237#issuecomment-302693219
  navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__).*/],
      // Don't precache sourcemaps (they're large) and build asset manifest:
  staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
  stripPrefix: './build'
}
```

Comment: The static content is generated and I did all the changes as described. It doesn't works for me. Chrome still displays index.html content. 
My preCacheConfig does updates nicely.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the list for all the markups generated from react-snapshot you can manually set the rewrite rules for them and then add a fallback rule for the rest.

**For Example**

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/signup",
    "destination": "/signup.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "/orders",
    "destination": "/orders.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Comment: this did not solve it , the index.html still renders first on all routes

Comment: These changes need to be done in serve.json. serve.json does not generate in bootstrap by CRA you need to add it to the public folder.  Also, you need to update the serve command with the serve -c serve.json build.
This works well without the service worker.